# Swift, Dictionary of String:String, best way to get an array of values, where the key contains a string?

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary, like this:
{"Matt":"Apple", "Calvin":"Nut", "Susie":"Pear"}

I want to check the `keys` of the dictionary with a string, to see if they contain that string-- and if they do, I want to add their respective `value` to an array

So, if the input was "a"
the return would be ["Apple", "Nut"] because "Matt" and "Calvin" matched the "a"

Basically looking for some Swift tips,
otherwise I was going to implement it like this:

- Grab all keys, put into an array
- Filter keys for string value, this is the keyArray
- Enumerate over keyArray, and get all their values from the dictionary
- Boom have an array of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the dictionary, using `contains()` on each key,
and then extract the corresponding values:

```
let dict = [ "Matt":"Apple", "Calvin":"Nut", "Susie":"Pear" ]
let input = "a"

let values = Array(dict.filter { $0.key.contains(input) }.values)
print(values) // ["Apple", "Nut"]
```

Or with `flatMap()` (renamed to `compactMap()` in Swift 4.1):

```
let values = dict.flatMap { $0.key.contains(input) ? $0.value : nil }
print(values) // ["Apple", "Nut"]
```

Here each dictionary entry is mapped to the value if the key contains
the given string, and to `nil` otherwise. `flatMap()` then returns an
array with the non-`nil` values.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using a `filter` over the dictionary:

```
let dict: [String: String] = ["Matt": "Apple", "Calvin": "Nut", "Susie": "Pear"]

func findValuesMatching(search: String, in dict: [String: String]) -> [String] {
    return dict
        .filter { (key, value) in
            return key.range(of: search) != nil
        }.map { (key, value) in
            return value
        }
}

print(findValuesMatching(search: "a", in: dict))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
let dict = ["Matt":"Apple", "Calvin":"Nut", "Susie":"Pear"]
let containsA = dict.filter({ $0.key.lowercased().contains("a") }).map({ $0.value })
```

Output:

```
["Apple", "Nut"]
```